# What chmod to edit a .txt from a .php

Tags: php, chmod

I've a test.txt file on same folder of myphp.php, test.txt is empty, myphp.php have this:

```
      <?php
        $g = fopen("test.txt", "w+");
        fwrite($g, 'some text here');
        fclose($g);
```

When I type www.mysite.com/myphp.php it will only work if I have public permission to "write" (ex 666) on the test.txt but I want it to work with 664, is it possible?

Comment: It's possible if the owner of `test.txt` is the same user that runs the web server process, or is in the same group as that user. (But note that giving your web server process the ability to write to the files it's serving is generally a really bad idea.)

Comment: why not use 644?

Comment: It's all about user/group permissions but on a webserver there's, generally speaking, very little point in giving *"guest"* users any permissions whatsoever - 660 should be good for a writeable text file; and it should be outside the document root.

Comment: 664 or 644 doesn't work, I'm trying to find on how make it work, the owner of the files seems to be the root: root@brbtc:/var/www/html/Test# ls -lh test.txt -rw-rwxr-- 1 root root 0 Apr 17 15:33 test.txt root@brbtc:/var/www/html/Test# ls -lh myphp.php -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 118 Apr 17 15:24 mypgp.php

Comment: You need to find out what user Apache is running under (assuming mod_php); it's likely to be *www-data* (but it could be anything) you'll want to `chown` the file to that user.

Comment: As that are only feel .txt files that I'll need to edit, I fixed it using: chown -R root:www-data test.txt, now it seems to be working right. Thank you all.